# Is it possible to clear the screen within ghostscript?

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I could not find the command to clear the screen within ghostscript under windows. Could you please help me?

[image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to clear the *text window*? How about:

```
28 { ()= } repeat    % output 28 blank lines
```

[*There are several short recipes to output a newline: `()=`, `()==`, `<>=`, `<>==`, `/ =`, `(\n)print`*]

In Linux, you can discover the appropriate terminal control string with `infocmp -L|grep clear_screen`.

Then you can emit a hex string. (Sadly, the PLRM does not provide `(\E)` to generate an escape.) For Konsole, it's:

```
<1b5b481b5b324a> print flush
```

or

```
(\033[H\033[2J) print flush
```

On windows, ghostscript implements its own terminal window; and while it probably has such a code, there is no `infocmp` to discover what it might be.

Comment: thanks, it works, but what's the syntax of the expression `()=`?

Comment: `()` creates an empty string; `=` prints it, followed by a newline. Another way would be `(\n) print`.

Comment: @Jichao: it is important to have in mind that this is a program sequence that prints 28 blank lines. Computer languages do not have a "clear screen"  for their interactive interpreter, as the built in BASIC interpreters - the interactie prompt is a _way_ to comunicate with the input-execute loop of the language, which just cares about its `stdin` channel, not the terminal it is running in. The termnal, on the other hand might have readline, lclear screen, copy and paste and other goodies. That is true for Python, Ghostscript, and other languages that feature an interactive prompt.

Answer (score 3):

`erasepage`, or `showpage`if you want to start a new page.

Comment: sorry for my input error, i **don't** mean to clear the page of a postscript document, but to clear the screen of the ghostscript, like a cls in cmd. But `erasepage` does not work for me.